# How to read system.web section from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, configuration-management

Should be simple, but whatever I try returns null:

```
const string key = "system.web";

var sectionTry1 = WebConfigurationManager.GetSection(key);

var sectionTry2 = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(key);
```

I'm sure I have done this before.

I am using MVC if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Was being an idiot - system.web is not a config section but a config group. If I change the key to an actual section, then both methods work fine. Here's the one using ConfigurationManager:

```
const string outputCacheSettingsKey = "system.web/caching/outputCacheSettings";           

var outputCacheSettingsSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(outputCacheSettingsKey) as OutputCacheSettingsSection;
```

Comment: For the record the same works if you need to get the compilation section, except that you cast it to `CompilationSection`

Answer (score 7):

I think accessing system.web is slightly different to accessing appSettings.

Try this:

```
string configPath = "/MyAppRoot";

Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(configPath);

IdentitySection section = (IdentitySection)config.GetSection("system.web/identity");
```

You need to cast the relevant section of system.web you're trying to access to a particular type.

Comment: First, check if `system.web/identity` ***section exists*** ?

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
public Int32 GetmaxRequestLength()
{
    // Set the maximum file size for uploads in bytes.
    var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/httpRuntime") as HttpRuntimeSection;
    // return length converted to kbytes or return default value as specified
    return (Int32) Math.Round((decimal)(section != null ? (double)section.MaxRequestLength * 1024 / 1000 : 5.120), 2);
}
```

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` reads ***machine.config*** or ***web.config*** ? Only I want read ***web.config***